# Digital Signage - What software to use?

Tags: software-rec, multiple-monitors

I have a monitor mounted to a wall, and I want to display information in a slideshow-like fashion, but would like to be able to put different types of continually updated content on each slide like:

- Weather information
- RSS Feed content
- The latest news

Is there any software that will do this?

Comment: What operating system are you on/willing to use?

Comment: Windows or Linux are options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for this. You can build a webpage that does this and run it full-screen, or if you are running linux, you can do some sneaky things.

For the linux option, you can use [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net) to grab and display weather, news, RSS feeds, etc... and then use a background image rotation system to have your slideshow going. Then just hide/remove the menu bars, and you're good to go.

The webpage option is probably going to look nicer, but the conky option is going to be faster and cheaper. Your choice, really.

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer in kiosk mode, or simply as an active desktop (after hiding all desktop icons).

There is an option somewhere to reload the page after N seconds